# Add Default Event Handler For All Selected Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a fair number of buttons on one form and I want to add separate click (default) event handler for each.  If I double click one control it adds the empty click event handler to the code behind.

Is there anyway for me to select, say 20, buttons and add a separate default handler for each?

I have tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> double click, <kbd>Alt</kbd> double click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> double click but they all do the same, add one event handler and assign it to all the controls.

**Edit**

I get that I could have the same event handler for all the buttons, work out which one was click etc etc.  This is not what I am asking.  I just wanted a quick way to add the empty click handler for all selected buttons.

Comment: how about copypaste and assign the events onLoad?

Comment: @Tomtom Sorry, yes it is.

Comment: @SebastianL if I went to that trouble I may as well double click each control one by one.  If I copy and paste I would still have to change the name of each event.

Comment: Select the desired ones, change the PROP view to Events, Click the Click event and it hooks the selected buttons up to the same handler

Comment: how about altering the basecontrol and add a default event then? or that what Plutonix said.

Comment: @Plutonix I did say that in the question. Its not what I want. Well kind of.  I don't want the same event handler I want separate ones as f I had double clicked each button individually.

Comment: @downvoter Any reason for the downvote or was it just a random click?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. Misunderstood the question, so removing the old answer as it's not really applicable.

My advice would be open the Form cs file in a text editor, find the region where the control/event bindings occur and copy, paste a particular Button line updating the event and id after.

Pretty laborious still.

Comment: Sorry, only just saw your comment to the other answer

Comment: I think you are over complicating things, but I appreciate the effort.  While this may well work its still more work than double clicking on 20 buttons. PS I am not the down voter..

Comment: No worries, I misunderstood the question somewhere, so the downvote is expected really.

Comment: Ultimately the events that are bound in the designer end up as assignations in the class. I'd say the best thing you could do is open up the form cs file in an editor and copy, paste that command for each button. It's laborious, but faster than double clicking buttons in a form.